# Using "%", "?" and "#" in java to find a substring

Tags: java, string, contains

I'm trying to go in a more effective way to find elements in a String different than having to convert the sentence into array of char and then comparing it against the other pieces of text, if you could please let me know if there is any other way you may know to do it,

What I need is

`Boolean b = myString.contains(important%urgent);`

and this should be different than:

`Boolean b = myString.contains(urgent%important);`

In the previous cases I want to get a True value if the words are contained in the String and they follow the specific order.

the next one is the ?

`Boolean b myString.contains(friend?); //this would look for 'friend' and 'friends' or so`

and the last one #

`Boolean b myString.equals(#/#/2013 #:#:#);//this would return true if the date is in 2013`

I hope I was able to explain myself, thanks for your answer.

Comment: This isn't clear.  What output are you expecting in the first two cases?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you looked at [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)?

Comment: I apologize, english is not my native language so maybe that's why I'm not being clear enough, I tried to explain my current solution, I'm first splitting my search into a String[], then I split every single result in a char[], then I compare each char and taking out a character every time this matches until the char[] is empty, I do that with every result.

Comment: I haven't looked for regular expressions, but I'm on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want regex!

#### To check word order:

```
Boolean b = myString.matches(".*important.*urgent.*");
```

Note, to be strict about "word" (ie to not match "unimportant"), add word boundaries:

```
Boolean b = myString.matches(".*\\bimportant\\b.*\\burgent\\b.*");
```

#### To check optional "s" at end of word:

```
Boolean b = myString.matches(".*friends?.*");
```

Again, to be strict and not match "friendly", add word boundaries:

```
Boolean b = myString.matches(".*\\bfriends?\\b.*");
```

#### To check for digits:

```
Boolean b = myString.matches("\\d+/\\d+/2013 \\d+:\\d+:\\d+");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try regular expression.

For example the last one:

```
Pattern p3 = Pattern.compile("^\d{2}/\d{2}/2013\s\d:\d:\d$");
Matcher m = p3.matcher(target);
if(m.matches()) {...}
```

Comment: You need to escape the back slashes inside a Java String.

Comment: Yes, you are right. :) Thanks. I hope something like ''' A raw string ''' in Java...